# Logon failed Crystal Report C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports

I have a C# Desktop project that use Crystal Report tool, my object is to call a SQL procedure and get the result of this procedures ( fields of tables ) shown in the Crystal Report `.rpt`.

In my computer this task worked well, but the problem is that I work with a team and when I have pushed the project to GitHub and my colleague pull my work and merge it to his version.

He got a problem of Connection ( Logon failed to the database ) and three lines of Exception in the Console :

> Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll
> Exception thrown: 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.LogOnException' in CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataSetConversion.dll
> Exception thrown: 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.LogOnException' in CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll
> Exception thrown: 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.LogOnException' in CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.dll

I would like to know how to set the connection parameters dynamically with Crystal Report, to make the connection success in the two PCs?

```
try
        {

            CrystalReport1 cry1 = new CrystalReport1();
            cry1.Load(@"CrystalReport1.rpt");
      
            GlobalConfig.sql.ConnectionString = GlobalConfig.connectionString;
            GlobalConfig gb = new GlobalConfig();
            using (IDbConnection connection = GlobalConfig.sql)
            {
                List<string> ls = new List<string>();
                ls = gb.getConnectionlogin();
                cry1.SetDatabaseLogon(ls[0], ls[1]); 
                                                 
                cry1.SetParameterValue("@institute_id", instituteid);
                cry1.SetParameterValue("@date_from", from1);

                cry1.SetParameterValue("@date_to", to1);
                cry1.SetParameterValue("institutename", institutename);
                crysview.ViewerCore.ReportSource = cry1;
            }

        }
        catch(Exception es)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error load file   " + es);
        }


    }
```

Comment: whats your connectionString, maybe it is different id password on your team side for the database, have they checked?

Comment: Yes there are different , I know that and I'm trying to make the set of the id and the password dynamically  using this line `cry1.SetDatabaseLogon(ls[0], ls[1]);` mention that `ls[0]` is the user and `ls[1]` is the password

Comment: As a note, it is pointless to assign `new List<string>()` to `ls`. Just write `List<string> ls = gb.getConnectionlogin();`

Comment: Thanks, you are right in this point , but this is not related to my problem that I have now , did you have any suggestion or any solution to my error? .

Comment: Instead of letting the crystal report read it's data, you're best reading it in code and presenting a List of poco to the viewer. So long as your property types and names match what the report was designed against, this will work fine. You can then use whatever approach to the database the rest of your app uses. And if you hit failures you'll be seeing regular ado issues.

Comment: Hard coding username and password is bad practice. Role based authentication is preferable. Give authorities to an ad group and put users in that group.